# moving range of values from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of distinct integer values, let's say from d7:o7 . I'd like to move these values to another location in the same work book (based on logic outside the scope of this question). What is the best way to do this?

My initial (failed) approach went a little like this:

create a variant

```
Dim myArray As Variant
```

assign values to array

```
myArray = Range("d7:o7")
```

output array of integers in a new range

```
Range("d10:o10") = myArray
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Range("D10:O10").Value = Range("d7:O7").Value
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That's more or less what I needed. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

This will **copy** (not delete the original values), assuming you are staying on the same sheet, but the column is represented as a number (E.G. A=1, B=2 etc.).  This example is for a 2 by 2 array, but you can easily change the start and end row and column numbers:

```
Sub CopyCells()

    Dim SrcBeginRowNum As Integer
    Dim SrcBeginColNum As Integer
    Dim SrcEndRowNum As Integer
    Dim SrcEndColNum As Integer

    Dim DstBeginRowNum As Integer
    Dim DstBeginColNum As Integer


    Dim ri As Integer
    Dim ci As Integer

    Dim dest_ri As Integer
    SrcBeginRowNum = 1
    SrcBeginColNum = 1
    SrcEndRowNum = 2
    SrcEndColNum = 2


    DstBeginRowNum = 34
    DstBeginColNum = 5

    dest_ri = DstBeginRowNum
    dest_ci = DstBeginColNum

    For ri = SrcBeginRowNum To SrcEndRowNum

        dest_ci = DstBeginColNum

        For ci = SrcBeginColNum To SrcEndColNum

            Cells(dest_ri, dest_ci).Value = Cells(ri, ci).Value
            dest_ci = dest_ci + 1

        Next
        dest_ri = dest_ri + 1


    Next



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleive the **best answer** is given above :) where you have accepted.

So I am posting this, in order to throw some perspective to what you started doing. You may do this  for `Transposing` data from ranges to arrays and vise versa. However when outputing it depends if you are using a multi-dimensional array or single-D array. We take `Sheet1` for the sample code.

```
Dim myArray As Variant
'--to array
myArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction_ 
            .Transpose(Sheets(2).Range("D7:O7").Value))
'--to sheet
Sheets(1).Range("D10").Resize(1, _ 
            UBound(Application.Transpose(myarray))) = myarray
```

I have used a double transpose to keep a multi-column from creating a 2D array. So it will look like the following:

[image]

Comment: @TomM. check this out, if you ever want to use Arrays and Ranges for data transferring :D